# Wordpress the_content showing all pages

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I'm working through a custom Wordpress theme and have run into a really strange problem, but I can't find the solution. Right now, I have two pages set up with dummy content and one is setup as a static front page. However, the content from both pages is getting pulled onto the homepage.

Here's a link to the live site. [wintonsmotionpictures.com](http://wintonsmotionpictures.com)

I've been stripping things down to basics to try and locate the problem. This is the content of my page.php file.

```
<?php
// Filename: page.php
get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

<div class="container">
<?php the_content();
 endwhile; endif; 
?>
</div>  

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And this is the HTML content that is getting spit out into Firebug.

```
<main>
  <section class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eu est condimentum, dictum nibh vitae, maximus arcu.</p>

        <div class="container">
          <p>Fusce mollis justo vitae porta porta. Proin congue fringilla quam et vehicula. Mauris commodo arcu sit amet neque elementum vestibulum.</p>
        </div>  

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Here also is my header.php file. Again, this whole theme is fairly stripped down.

```
    <?php
/*
 Filename: header.php
 Author: Jesse Winton
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title><?php
    /*
     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
     */
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    ?></title>

<!-- stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,700|Merriweather:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- / stylesheets -->

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- / scripts -->

<!-- meta tags -->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="author" content="Jesse Winton Design"/>
<meta name="robots" content="Index, Follow"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />  
<!-- / meta tags -->

<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

  <body>

   <?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'page', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
                          <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                          <?php endwhile; endif; ?> 

    <main>

    <section class="wrapper">
        <div class="content-wrap">
```

I can't for the life of me locate the problem here. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jesse

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow you, but you have a loop in `page.php` that's going through all your posts, and calling `the_content` for each one. Why would you expect it just to pick up the front page?

Comment: @andrewsi see my edit, included a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be looping on page.php template. Simply call `the_post()` once.

```
<?php
// Filename: page.php
get_header();

the_post(); ?> 

<div class="container">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>  

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This query within header.php is obstructing the actual post query. Remove it and you'll see the appropriate content in the appropriate places:

```
   <?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'page', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
                          <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                          <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

You should instead use `WP_Query()` and `wp_reset_postdata();`. In the interim, try adding `wp_reset_postdata();` as the last line of header.php.

Comment: Thanks, but now it only displays the content from the front page, even on the About dummy page. Again, it's a super stripped down version of the site, but the link is [here.](http://wintonsmotionpictures.com)

Comment: Yes, it does but the actual content in the `.container` div is the same as the homepage. If you look at my original post, you'll see the content on each page is different.